# Did Aquinas rate rage as worse than sexual sins?

Tags: sin, thomas-aquinas

I have been explained that Thomas Aquinas regarded sexual sins as less serious than sins connected with rage, as the former gave a taste of the divine, whereas the latter had a diabolical origin.

What would be a solid reference for this, if any?

Comment: What do you mean by "rage"? Anger (_ira_)? Hatred (_odium_)?

Comment: In general, Pride is considered worse than Anger, which is again worse than Lust. The "intellectual" sins being worse than the "fleshy" sins.

Answer (score 2):

I think by "rage" you mean anger (*ira*).

St. Thomas, in [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 158 a. 4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS158.html#SSQ158A4THEP1) ("Whether anger is the most grievous sin?") co., argues that "envy (*invidia*) ['is more grievous'] than anger (*ira*): since it is worse to desire evil as an evil". (Envy is to desire an evil for somebody, which is always wrong; [anger can sometimes be lawful](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS158.html#SSQ158A1THEP1).)

[Envy (*invidia*) is a capital vice](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS036.html#SSQ36A4THEP1); [lust (*luxuria*) is a capital vice](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS153.html#SSQ153A4THEP1), too. Angels can only commit sins of pride (*superbia*) and envy (*invidia*), which do not depend upon having a body like the other capital vices.

Discussing whether fornication is the most grievous sin, St. Thomas writes ([*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 154 a. 3](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS154.html#SSQ154A3THEP1) co.):

> The gravity of a sin may be measured in two ways, first with regard to the sin in itself, secondly with regard to some accident. The gravity of a sin is measured with regard to the sin itself, by reason of its species, which is determined according to the good to which that sin is opposed. Now fornication is contrary to the good of the child to be born. Wherefore it is a graver sin, as to its species, than those sins which are contrary to external goods, such as theft and the like; while **it is less grievous than those which are directly against God**, and sins that are injurious to the life of one already born, such as murder.

Comment: I do not see the comparison with erotical sins.

Comment: Yes, I probably meant anger.

Comment: David took another man's wife sexually, had her husband killed, and said that against God alone he had sinned (Psalm 51:4).  All sin is ultimately, directly against God and a rating system is superfluous.